# Android Release apps crash immediately after 64 bit upgrade on android

Tags: android, react-native, 64-bit

After updating react native to 64 bits, by adding the x86_64 and arm64_v8a abi filters. The release app is not working. I can build and install it, but opening it crashes immediately. Logcat produces a lot of text but I can't figure out which is the real error and which are consequences.

Currently on RN 0.59.8, gradle tools 3.4.1 and gradle 5.1.1-all.

Ran both `react-native run-android --variant=release` and `./gradlew assembleRelease`

Fails on both

Ran `./gradlew bundleRelease` but I did not know how to install the aab that it produced, assumed that was meant to be uploaded to store only to let them handle it.

I tried upgrading gradle, downgrading gradle, updating react native (to 0.60, but it crashed due to well known hermes errors and could not make it work). Tried installing and uninstalling packages... nothing has gone beyond crashing at startup

Some gradle context

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        renderscriptTargetApi 21
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    .
    .
    .
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
.
.
.
dependencies {

implementation project(':react-native-config')
    // implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-webview')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_slider')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-sound')
    implementation project(':react-native-sentry')
    implementation project(':react-native-code-push')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-video')
    implementation project(':react-native-keep-awake')
    implementation project(':react-native-contacts')
    implementation project(':react-native-unified-contacts')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation project(':react-native-moengage')
    implementation 'com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:+'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_blur')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1'
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    // implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
    implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0') {
        force = true;
    }

}
.
.
.
```

If I run logcat while it crashes, the following gets my attention first, this is the first stacktrace that appears

```
07-20 13:52:27.489 29133 29167 D SoLoader: About to load: libreactnativejni.so
07-20 13:52:27.490 29133 29167 D SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/PACKAGENAME/lib-main
07-20 13:52:27.490 29133 29167 D SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so found on /data/app/PACKAGENAME-1/lib/arm
07-20 13:52:27.490 29133 29167 D SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libreactnativejni.so
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     : Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(android.view.View) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:457)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(android.view.View) (AppCompatActivity.java:145)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.loadApp(java.lang.String) (ReactActivityDelegate.java:89)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (ReactActivityDelegate.java:75)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (ReactActivity.java:52)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6672)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1140)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2612)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2724)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1473)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6123)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:757)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/PACKAGENAME-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/PACKAGENAME-1/lib/arm, /data/app/PACKAGENAME-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(android.view.View) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:457)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(android.view.View) (AppCompatActivity.java:145)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.loadApp(java.lang.String) (ReactActivityDelegate.java:89)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (ReactActivityDelegate.java:75)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (ReactActivity.java:52)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6672)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1140)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2612)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2724)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1473)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6123)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-20 13:52:27.502 29133 29133 I art     :   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Afterwards I can see several SOloader issues like

```
07-20 13:52:27.546 29133 29167 D SoLoader: About to load: libfb.so
07-20 13:52:27.546 29133 29167 D SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/PACKAGENAME/lib-main
07-20 13:52:27.546 29133 29167 D SoLoader: libfb.so found on /data/app/PACKAGENAME-1/lib/arm
07-20 13:52:27.546 29133 29167 D SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libfb.so
07-20 13:52:27.549 29133 29167 D SoLoader: About to load: libfb.so
07-20 13:52:27.550 29133 29167 D SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/PACKAGENAME/lib-main
07-20 13:52:27.550 29133 29167 D SoLoader: libfb.so found on /data/app/PACKAGENAME-1/lib/arm
07-20 13:52:27.550 29133 29167 D SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libfb.so
```

Finally I can see the packager error, which I find quite weird since it's a release app

```
07-20 13:52:27.622 29133 29167 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
07-20 13:52:27.622 29133 29167 E AndroidRuntime: Process: PACKAGENAME, PID: 29133
07-20 13:52:27.622 29133 29167 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
07-20 13:52:27.622 29133 29167 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
07-20 13:52:27.622 29133 29167 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:218)
07-20 13:52:27.622 29133 29167 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:31)
07-20 13:52:27.622 29133 29167 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:247)
07-20 13:52:27.622 29133 29167 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1152)
07-20 13:52:27.622 29133 29167 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$900(ReactInstanceManager.java:123)
07-20 13:52:27.622 29133 29167 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:943)
07-20 13:52:27.622 29133 29167 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Downgrade your gradle tool version to 3.3.X and gradle version to 4.x

Answer (score 0):

I think RN 0.59.x doesn't support AndroidX. That seems like the reason of the crash. The first RN version supporting AndroidX is RN 0.60.0. Avoid importing any library contain "androidx", such as "androidx.appcompat:appcompat".

Comment: I've been running androidx safely on 0.59.8 for a while. I have postinstall script running `npx jetify` with jetifier much like 0.60 does. The error popped up somewhere after updating everything to 64 bits

Answer (score 0):

try to delete `index.android.bundle` in src > main > assets/ if already exists

and then run below command in root of your project

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

then run below command one-by-one

```
 react-native start --reset-cache
 cd android 
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assemblerelease
```

this should also resolve the issue like JS file changes not reflecting in released apk

Answer (score 0):

This will most likely be related not to RN itself but for a dependency and the use of AndroidX. What you posted lacks some information to be sure and sadly you have a lot of native dependencies to check.

1. If you are using jetifier I have found that it sometimes does not work, for example if some module has a jar or other already compiled SDK.
2. If you updated RN but the dependencies are not fixed version you might have updated to a new one that assumes you are in RN 0.60 which needs androix and does not use the support library.

You would need to check the dependencies and their latest updrade and make sure you are using the latest that DOES NOT force androidx support and disable jetifier.

If you must use androidx then you have to wait until all dependencies migrate fully to androidx

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue of SoLoader and was fixed in v0.9.0

https://github.com/facebook/SoLoader/releases